# Rails 5 has_many_through include pivot table in result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app with restaurants and products. One product has_many restaurant and one restaurant has many products. I created a pivot table and created and has_many_through relation since I want to work with the pivot table.

Product:

```
has_many :restaurant_products, dependent: :destroy
has_many :restaurants, through: :restaurant_products
```

Restaurant:

```
has_many :restaurant_products, dependent: :destroy
has_many :products, through: :restaurant_products
```

Since every restaurant can modify the price for each product I have added a custom_price column to my restaurant_products table.

Now I can get all products for a certain restaurant:

```
@restaurant.products
```

But this way, when I list the products, I don't have access to the custom price. How can I somehow include or access the correct pivot record to get the custom price?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
@restaurant.restaurant_products.joins(:products).select('restaurant_products.custom_price, products.*')
```

That will give you access to instances including all of a product's columns, as well as the join table's custom price.

The SQL generated will look similar to:

```
SELECT restaurant_products.custom_price, products.* 
FROM `restaurant_products` 
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `restaurant_products`.`product_id` 
WHERE `restaurant_products`.`restaurant_id` = 1
```

Quick tip: what's returned might look a little strange, something like:

```
[#<RestaurantProduct id: 1, custom_price: 10>]
```

...though if you call `attributes`, or a product attribute on an instance here, you'll have access to everything you want.

---

The above gives quick and efficient access to the records' data, though if you need to access methods on the product itself, you might prefer the following:

```
@product_details = @restaurant.restaurant_products.includes(:products)
```

And then to loop through the data:

```
@product_details.each do |product_detail|
  product_detail.custom_price

  product_detail.product.column_data
  product_detail.product.a_method
end
```

Hope these help - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a custom select that includes the row from the join table:

```
@products = @restaurant.products
           .select('products.*, restaurant_products.custom_price')
```

This returns `restaurant_products.custom_price` as if it where a column on `products`. You can us `AS` to provide a alias if you want to call it something else than `custom_price`.

So you can do:

```
<table>
  # ...
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.custom_price %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, it always better to query on pivot table as bellow

```
@restaurant_products = RestaurantProduct.includes(:product)
                                        .where(restaurant_id: @restaurant.id)
```

You can display it in the view simply as follows.

```
<table>
  <% @restaurant_products.each do |resta_product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= resta_product.product.name %></td>
    <td><%= resta_product.custom_price %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

You can even delegate all product methods to work directly on `restaurant_product`.